# How to replace multiple items in a list and make a dataframe of it?

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe

I have a quiet complex list where I try to change 2 things:

1. `id` has to become `ID`
2. `Field1` has to become `Value1`

After that I try to make a neat DataFrame of it. This is my expected outcome:

```
    ID    - Value1 
0    1    - 1235
1    2    - 5631
2    3    - 9875
3    4    - 2683
4    5    - 97525
5    6    - 6614
```

**`my_list` looks like this:**

```
my_list = [('www.url1.com'), 1000, [{'id': 1, 'Field1': 1235}, {'id': 2, 'Field1': 5631}, {'id': 3, 'Field1': 9875}, 'www.google.com)'],
            ('www.url1.com'), 1000, [{'id': 4, 'Field1': 2683}, {'id': 5, 'Field1': 97525}, {'id': 6, 'Field1': 6614}, 'www.google.com)']]
```

This is the code I tried to use. I don't get any errors, but neither do I get the expected result.

```
import pandas as pd

my_list = [('www.url1.com'), 1000, [{'id': 1, 'Field1': 1235}, {'id': 2, 'Field1': 5631}, {'id': 3, 'Field1': 9875}, 'www.google.com)'],
            ('www.url1.com'), 1000, [{'id': 4, 'Field1': 2683}, {'id': 5, 'Field1': 97525}, {'id': 6, 'Field1': 6614}, 'www.google.com)']]

  
for n, i in enumerate(my_list):
    if i == 'id':
        my_list[n] = 'ID'
        

# print(my_list)

df = pd.DataFrame(my_list)

#print(df)
```

Comment: why other elements in list not included in dataframe?

Comment: @deadshot because those are not relevant for my dataframe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data you need inside the list. you can use `isinstance` to filter the list and then inside the list select all element whose are type `dict` then create the new dictionary using the new keys `{'id': 'ID', 'Field1': 'Value1'}`.

```
keys = {'id': 'ID', 'Field1': 'Value1'}

res = []
for x in my_list: 
    if isinstance(x, list):
        res += [{keys[k]: y[k] for k in keys} for y in x if isinstance(y, dict)]

df = pd.DataFrame(res)
print(df)
```

Using list comprehension

```
keys = {'id': 'ID', 'Field1': 'Value1'}
res = [y for x in my_list if isinstance(x, list) for y in x if isinstance(y, dict)]
df = pd.DataFrame(res).rename(columns=keys)
```

**Output:**

```
   ID  Value1
0   1    1235
1   2    5631
2   3    9875
3   4    2683
4   5   97525
5   6    6614
```

Comment: Thx. You did great, can you explain maybe what you did?

Comment: Why when I apply your code to a much bigger my_list I get no result back?

Comment: try printing the `res` is it empty?

Answer (score 0):

You can select just the lists with the ids and put them together:

```
from functools import reduce
my_list = [('www.url1.com'), 1000, [{'id': 1, 'Field1': 1235}, {'id': 2, 'Field1': 5631}, {'id': 3, 'Field1': 9875}, 'www.google.com)'],
            ('www.url1.com'), 1000, [{'id': 4, 'Field1': 2683}, {'id': 5, 'Field1': 97525}, {'id': 6, 'Field1': 6614}, 'www.google.com)']]

a = reduce(lambda x,y: x+y,[my_list[2::3][i][-2::-1] for i in range(len(my_list[2::3]))])

pd.DataFrame(a).rename(columns = {"id":"ID","Field1":"Value1"})
```

Output:

```
    ID  Value1
0   3   9875
1   2   5631
2   1   1235
3   6   6614
4   5   97525
5   4   2683
```

Just sort by ID if you need it.

Comment: Looks proper, but quiet complex... Thank you though.